Issue with Longtable, endhead, and Hline causing table reformatting
So I am trying to have the caption for my longtable appear on multiple pages, which it does with endhead but it also adds some weird table reformatting issues to the top of my table.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{5.3cm}|}

\caption{Topic Modelling} \endhead
\label{table:3}
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}
\hline
\textbf{Stuff} & \textbf{More stuff} & \textbf{extra stuff} & \textbf{so on} \\
\hline
...


I have attached an image with the related issue. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

remove \label{table:3} \setlength\extrarowheight{10pt} they just force a row with a single cell and setting the extrarowheight within a table cell doesn't do anything useful you need to set it before the table

please always post an exaple that shows the problem not just a fragment. don't you get a tex error at the \hline ? if you get any error always ask about the error not the pdf you may get by scrolling past the error.

There is no error message that appears. Removing both works but how would I reference the table in the text without the label?

put the label in the argument to caption, or in any cell not (as you have it there after \endhead but before \hline which surely gave an error?

if I complete your snippet it errors. You should get a red circle in overleaf.
